# TextBox.SelectAll() does not justify text to left in silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I have given a fixed width to the textbox and I don't want to wrap the text too. So the problem here is if I enter text larger then the width then on GotFocus event of a textbox I do the following :

```
txtperson.SelectAll();
```

But it doesn't justify the text from left ?
Any help how can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, what you can easily do is to retemplate your textbox. when it gets focus you just change background color of the text and it will does the trick.

Comment: Hey i really want to show the all text selected so i cant simple play with the background and get away..:)